# How to extend Data to product

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I want to add data to a product, when adding this item to the cart. I am adding dynamic data as an extension, so that I am able to change the product price.
When setting the extension in the `addLineItems` function in `CartLineItemController`, I am not able to retrieve this data in a decorated `ProductPriceCalculator` inside the `calculate` function.

```php
addLineItems(...){
return Profiler::trace('cart::add-line-item', function () use ($cart, $requestDataBag, $request, $context) {
    /** @var RequestDataBag|null $lineItems */
    $lineItems = $requestDataBag->get('lineItems');
    if (!$lineItems) {
        throw new MissingRequestParameterException('lineItems');
    }

    $count = 0;

    try {
        $items = [];
        /** @var RequestDataBag $lineItemData */
        foreach ($lineItems as $lineItemData) {
            $lineItem = new LineItem(
                $lineItemData->getAlnum('id'),
                $lineItemData->getAlnum('type'),
                $lineItemData->get('referencedId'),
                $lineItemData->getInt('quantity', 1)
            );

            $criteria = new Criteria();
            $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('id', $lineItem->getId()));

            /** @var ProductEntity $product */
            $product = $this->productRepository->search(new Criteria(), $context->getContext())->first();

            $data = [
                'unit' => $lineItemData->get('unit'),
                'factor' => $lineItemData->get('factor')
            ];

            $extension = new ArrayStruct();
            $extension->assign($data);

            $product->addExtension('custom_extension', $extension));
}

public function calculate(iterable $products, SalesChannelContext $context): void
{
    /** @var SalesChannelProductEntity $product */
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $unit = $product->getExtension('custom_extension')->getVars()['unit'];
        $factor = (float)$product->getExtension('custom_extension')->getVars()['factor'];

        /** @var PriceCollection $price */
        $price = $product->getPrice();//
        $price->first()->setGross($price->first()->getGross() * $factor);
        $price->first()->setNet($price->first()->getNet() * $factor);
    }
    $this->getDecorated()->calculate($products, $context);
}
```

Am I totally wrong and is this realized in a complete different approach?

Comment: Your product entity is not the one that is used for the price calculation of the line item, And neither is the data persisted. The products are fetched at the ProductCartProcessor.
I would recommend saving the data as an extension of the line item, or its payload.